# Is there a more straightforward way to understand $\frac{\partial L}{\partial ( \partial_\mu \phi )} = \partial^\mu \phi$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, notation, variational-calculus

I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to understand $\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} = \partial^\mu \phi$ for a real scalar field $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial^\mu\phi)(\partial_\mu\phi) - V(\phi)
$.

Here's what I did by expanding the indices:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \left[ \frac{1}{2} (\partial^\nu\phi)(\partial_\nu\phi) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial (\partial^\nu\phi)}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} (\partial_\nu\phi) + (\partial^\nu\phi) \frac{\partial (\partial_\nu\phi)}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \delta^\nu_\mu (\partial_\nu\phi) + (\partial^\nu\phi) \delta^\nu_\mu \right] \\
&= \partial^\mu \phi.
\end{align}

Does this seem correct? Is there a more straightforward way to see why there is a raise in index from $\partial_\mu$ to $\partial^\mu$ when we take the derivative?

Comment: You are mostly right with the following corrections: $\frac{\partial(\partial^\nu \phi)}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} = \eta^{\mu\nu}$ and $\frac{\partial(\partial_\nu \phi)}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} = \delta^\mu_\nu$

Comment: It's just a generalization of $\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}}(\frac12\dot{q}^2-V(q))=\dot{q}$.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found things like $\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}$ to cause confusion are errors  when calculating  functional derivatives--- especially with up and down indices.  It's much easier to always go back to the basic definition of the functional derivative
$$
\delta S= \int d^dx  \left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi} \right)\delta \phi.
$$
For your case
$$
\delta S = \delta \int d^dx \frac 12 g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi\\
=  \int d^dx \frac 12 g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu \delta \phi)  \partial_\nu \phi+
 \int d^dx \frac 12 g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \phi (\partial_\nu \delta \phi)\\=
-\int d^dx \frac 12 g^{\mu\nu}(\delta \phi)  \partial^2_{\nu\mu} \phi-
 \int d^dx \frac 12 g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2_{\nu\mu} \phi (\delta \phi)\\=
\int d^dx (- g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2_{\mu\nu}\phi) (\delta \phi)\\
= \int d^dx(-\partial^\mu\partial_\mu \phi) \delta \phi.
$$