Four gradient relation
I'm doing an exercise in QFT and I have to calculate the energy-momentum tensor for the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian and by doing it I got the following term:
$$ \frac{\partial \ \partial^{\nu}\phi}{\partial \left( \partial^{\mu} \phi\right)} = \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}.\tag{1}$$
Is this evaluation correct?
I only found that the following relation holds: $$ \frac{\partial \ \partial_{\nu}\phi}{\partial \left( \partial_{\mu} \phi \right)} = \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}.\tag{2}$$

May be related/helpful in this context: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783623/

Yes, eq. (1) is correct.

@Qmechanic Thanks. I tried to derive it and I got the following:
$$ \frac{\partial \ \partial^{\nu}\phi}{\partial \left( \partial^{\mu} \phi\right)} = \frac{\partial \ g^{\nu\mu} \partial_{\mu}\phi}{\partial \left( g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu} \phi\right)} = \frac{g^{\nu\mu}}{g^{\mu\nu}} \frac{\partial \ \partial_{\mu}\phi}{\partial \left( \partial_{\nu} \phi\right)} = \frac{g^{\nu\mu}}{g^{\mu\nu}} \ \delta^{\nu}_{\mu} $$ where in the last part I used the above mentioned relation which I found that holds. But I am unsure about the fraction with the metric tensors. Is my approach even good?

And if it is, how to resolve the fraction with the metric tensors

Well, your comment formula has issues with the indices, but that can be fixed.

Where exactly? And how is the fraction with the metric tensors resolved?
